# How to Pull/Clone git repository over a VPN in Jenkins?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, gitlab, devops

We have a remote GitLab server which we can only access over a VPN connection.

How to make Jenkins to connect to that Gitlab repository over the VPN and clone/pull the source code?

The VPN client we are using is "VPN Access Manager".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup site-to-site vpn connection from your jenkins hosted network to the gitlab. Assuming both are in different remote locations.